# Explain why j is coming up with 150?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int i=3,j;  
  j=++i*++i*++i;
  printf("%d,%d",i,j);
}
```

The answer is upcoming up with i=6, j=150 
Please explain why j is coming up with 150??

Comment: Holy UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!

Comment: No return value, j not initialized.. what else can go wrong?

Comment: for i=3,j=4*5*6=120.When i=6 this goes j=7*8*9=504. So, I have no idea why j == 150!

Comment: You should never write stuff like `j=++i*++i*++i;`. Even if you know about sequence points (and all its consequences), the reader of your code does not know that you know.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix no problem with `j` not being initialized at declaration, since it is in the following line, also, at last c++ doesn't require a return statement for `main`.

Comment: @pepper_chico I'm aware the problem has something to do with the `++` which could be cached or not.. UB. a void main wouldn't require a return. a `int main` should.

Comment: its not related to j being uninitialized..its simply UB..http://ideone.com/yeOjq2

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: no need to initialize, and  no need for return value (at least, since C99. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c ). so yes, a lot of things can go wrong ;)

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix in c++ at last, it doesn't require. Not sure about the c standard, I think it's even more relaxed.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what value will be returned by a `int main` by default then? 0?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: yes. 0.

Comment: What was that editing in order to put the brace on the declaration? It makes the code less readable!

Comment: The code is perfectly correct!!

Comment: The code is perfectly correct!! But after complilation the answer is coming i=6, j=150. I don't know why it is giving 150 instead of 120.  If i talk about the logic, since we know i++ mean firstly `i=i+1;`   then `j=i;` by this, we get i=6 that's perfect right. But at j it should be `j=4*5*6` that will giving 120, but after complilation it is giving 150.! :(

Answer (score 9):

This Undefined behaviour is because of Sequence Points. See these links

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html

Answer (score 2):

This `j=++i*++i*++i` in your compiler will break into `1:(++i*++i)*++i` then it will calculate the left operand and then the right one. The left one is a parenthesis so it will see what's inside. That `++i*++i` will be evaluated as `(++i)*(++i)`, then the compiler will calculate the left and right operands and then it will do the multiplication. The left operand will increase `i` by one and return `i`, right operand will increase `i` by one and will return `i`. So we got `i*i` in the first parenthesis of the `1` expression, `i` is `5` so it will return `25`. Now we got `(25)*(++i)`, compiler checks both operands, left one returns `25`, right one increases `i` by one and returns `i`, `i` is now `6` so we got `25*6=150`. This is how gcc works

Comment: This looks interesting. However when i=3, j=(++i)*(++i)*(++i) => j=(4)*(5)*(6) but, this is not accurate because i is now 6, so j=6*6*6 which is not 150. Why does it do 5*5, first, then * 6?

Comment: Because when it does the first multiplication, it had to evaluate the "++" which affect the same register. Then the value is stored in an accumulator... when the last ++i is done it is multiplied with the accumulator.

Comment: Actually `j=(5)*(5)*(6)`. Parser first evaluates what is inside the parentheses then it makes the multiplication.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης but this is all good an fun but since the `++` is used, the result will mostly depend on the compilator. Using clang, it works as intended.

Comment: This means j=(6)*(6)*(6), as I said. *First* the parenthesis, then multiplication

Comment: eval=i*i breaks the priorities of operators...So, It *is* UB.

Comment: have you ever seen how compilers work?

Comment: Your order of execution simulates j=((++i)*(++i))*(++i);

Comment: As it was pointed out clang calculates it correctly. If it is depended on the compiler, it is UB.

Comment: @ThunderGr the UB is that you might be modifying the same register multiple times. there is no difference between `((++i)*(++i))*(++i)` and `(++i)*((++i)*(++i))`.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Of course there isn't a difference between the two but there is a difference between them and (++i)*(++i)*(++i) <> ((++i)*(++i)) * (++i)

Comment: there is no correct answer at `++i*++i*++i`, he said why does it give 150 I answered him why it gives 150....Other compiler can do whatever it likes

Comment: You need to specify that it is UB and that his *specific compiler* does it this way because it calculates like that, IMO.

Comment: Think about it, clang probably does that: `j = ++i; b= ++i; c=++i; j = j * b; j = j * c;`

Comment: In addition your claim that it calculates (++i)*(++i)*(++i) is wrong. It calculates ((++i)*(++i))*(++i)

Comment: yeah sure. but for speed and memory eficiency compilers like gcc must make other decisions than clang does

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799800/explain-why-j-is-coming-up-with-150#comment32987375_21800069 this is the same thing.

Comment: @ThunderGr do you understand that a computer cannot calculate 3 values at the same time? it has to create a temporary register to compute `i*i*i` And the order there doesn't matter left to right or right to left. You get the same result.

Comment: we are in binary computers so 2 things will be done first, that's how registers work, Loic said the same thing

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix This is irrelevant, really. When it does ((++i)*(++i)) *(++i), you have ((5)*(5)) * (++i)=>25*(6)=150

Comment: You'd have `6*6*6` only if the compiler wanted to evaluate the `++` first. Which mean, you can have at least 3 possible results for the code posted above. 120, 150 and 216.

Comment: @ThunderGr the other way around you'd have `6 * 25` or something else... You could end up with `4 * 36`

Comment: please stop commenting guys, if you have an argument talk to chat, not here. I am being spammed right now...

Comment: if `j=++i*++i*++i;` in the same line by replacing `eval=++i*++i;` `++i;` `j=eval*++i;` What will be the answer and why??

Comment: as we know i++ means `i=i+1;` then assign `j=i;` by this logic it should be `j=4*5*6` but you are saying `j=5*5*6` It's contradiction! :(

Comment: @Sudheesh It does calculations first in parentheses then it multiplies.

Answer (score 1):

The result is actually depend on the compiler.

I have compiled it with gcc and clang.  Gcc outputs 150, and clang outputs 120.

But the disassemble can give the reason why j = 150:

```
movl   $0x3,-0xc(%rbp)  // i = 3
movl   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp) // j = 0
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax  // %eax = i = 3
add    $0x1,%eax        // %eax += 1, %eax = 4 
mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)  // move %eax back to i, ie i = 4
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax  // %eax = i = 4
add    $0x1,%eax        // %eax = 5
mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)  // move %eax back to i, ie i = 5
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax  // store i in %eax
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%ecx  // store i in %ecx
imul   %ecx,%eax        // %eax * %ecx, %eax = 5*5 = 25
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%ecx  // store i in %ecx
add    $0x1,%ecx        // %ecx + 1, %ecx = 6
mov    %ecx,-0xc(%rbp)  // move %ecx back to i, ie i = 6 
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%ecx  // store i in %ecx
imul   %ecx,%eax        // %eax * %ecx, %eax = 6*25=150
mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp) // move %eax to j, ie j = 150
```

Comment: as I said in my answer with less details.